# Case Statement with multiple columns and each with a specific name

Tags: mysql

There is probably a simpler way of doing this but for now I am using a union to get my results. In my query, I end up with 2 rows of data regardless of the driver column. 
The desired result would be to exclude that row from the results if the driver column is null but if it is not null it needs to be included.

2 rows would be the maximum and no rows if both are null.

is this possible?

Query:

SELECT 
    ROUND(CASE
            WHEN _235 is not null THEN '0' ELSE ''
            END,5) AS mi_factor1,
    ROUND(CASE
            WHEN _235 is not null THEN '0' ELSE ''
            END,5) AS mi_factor2
FROM myDataBase

UNION

SELECT 
    ROUND(CASE
            WHEN _230 is not null THEN '0' ELSE ''
          END,5) AS mi_factor1,
    ROUND(CASE
            WHEN _230 is not null THEN '0' ELSE ''
          END,5) AS  mi_factor2
FROM los.e

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to exclude then best to have a where clause with the criteria what not to include

Since you are using a UNION that it would put the resultset of both query together for output

However you can try the following which uses the DISTINCT function on the resultset so you only have one row

> SELECT DISTINCT mi_factor1,mi_factor2 FROM (
>
> SELECT ROUND(CASE WHEN _235 is not null THEN '0' ELSE '' END,5) AS mi_factor1, ROUND(CASE WHEN _235 is not null THEN '0' ELSE '' END,5) AS mi_factor2 FROM myDataBase
>
> UNION
>
> SELECT ROUND(CASE WHEN _230 is not null THEN '0' ELSE '' END,5) AS mi_factor1, ROUND(CASE WHEN _230 is not null THEN '0' ELSE '' END,5) AS mi_factor2 FROM los.e
>
> )

You may also look at using GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL. Do not use a case statement if you do not want the data it has to be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all you answers, especially with limited information but I was able to answer my own question (the distinct and group by didn't work on my query).

it was simply adding an additional "and" line in the "where" clause.

in my scenario above, I used

SELECT column1, column2, etc...
FROM mydb
WHERE this is that
AND _235 is not null

UNION
same as above but the AND would be _230 is no null

again, I didn't provide key information and you'd have to make a lot of assumptions. This probably didn't make any sense or add any value to anyone with the same question but hope that at least on person gets something out of this. Later